# Define Pass statement in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the best answer to this question.

Answer - A Pass statement in Python is used when we cannot decide what to do in our code, but we must type something to make it syntactically correct.

is it correct?

Comment: Correct, Mostly it is used while handling errors/ warnings just to make the user comfortable while using the application.

Comment: `pass` is simply a statement that does nothing. You can use it where the syntax requires a statement but you need nothing to be done (e.g. in an erorr handler) or if you create a stub for functions etc. to be filled later.

Comment: Generally speaking, the “pass” statement is merely a null operation. Specifically, when it is executed, nothing happens.

Therefore, the “pass” statement is usually utilised as a placeholder syntactically. When there is no code needs to be executed, we can put the “pass” statement over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> pass is a null operation — when it is executed, nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically, but no code needs to be executed.

The [pass statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) in python acts as a placeholder for your future code. As the body of the loops and if condition cannot be empty in python, they cannot be left empty. However, it is possible that you have not yet decided what will happen if an `if condition` gets true. Then, you can use `pass` to avoid getting error and your code will not break.

```
# An if condition where the action is yet not known
if my_test_var == desired value:
    pass
```